# Error while importing AKS to Rancher 2.6.2

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have deployed Rancher 2.6.2 via helm, when importing existing aks cluster in Rancher, it's giving error:

[image]

Below error is at pod level:

```
{APIGroups:["rke-machine-config.cattle.io"], Resources:["*"], Verbs:["create"]}; resolution errors: [[clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "system:discovery" not found]], requeuing
```

Manifest for cluster role and clusterrolebinding:

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name:rancher-cr
  namespace: rancher-demo
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - statefulsets
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - create
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
```

& cluster role binding:

```
---
# Source: rancher/templates/clusterRoleBinding.yaml
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: rancher-crb
  namespace: rancher-demo
  labels:
    chart: rancher-2.6.2
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: rancher-sa
  namespace: rancher-demo
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: rancher-cr
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes is it? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: azure kuberntes cluster 1.21.7 and rancher version 2.6.1 , as unable to import aks on rancher ui